# How to launch an activity of an imported project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I created an android project (Project A) and inside it I imported another project (Project B) with:

> ->File/New/Import Module..

Now I want to call an activity located inside Project B from Project A.

I used:

```
Intent myIntent = new   Intent(this,Class.forName("com.projectB.app.MainActivity")); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But I get

> ClassNotFoundException

How to resolve this?

**UPDATE**

I found that I need to add the Project B as a dependency to Project A by using:

> Project Structure/Dependencies/+

When I try to build I get this error:

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> >     Could not resolve project :3dviewerobj.
> >          Required by:
> >              project :app
> >     Unable to find a matching configuration of project :3dviewerobj:
> >               - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
> >                   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found
> >     compatible value 'debug'.
> >                   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
> >     found incompatible value 'Apk'.
> >                   - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but
> >     wasn't required.
> >                   - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> >               - Configuration 'debugMetadataElements':
> >                   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found
> >     compatible value 'debug'.
> >                   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
> >     found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
> >                   - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but
> >     wasn't required.
> >                   - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
> >               - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
> >                   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found
> >     compatible value 'debug'.
> >                   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
> >     found incompatible value 'Apk'.
> >                   - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but
> >     wasn't required.
> >                   - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
> >               - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
> >                   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found
> >     incompatible value 'release'.
> >                   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
> >     found incompatible value 'Apk'.
> >                   - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but
> >     wasn't required.
> >                   - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> >               - Configuration 'releaseMetadataElements':
> >                   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found
> >     incompatible value 'release'.
> >                   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
> >     found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
> >                   - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but
> >     wasn't required.
> >                   - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
> >               - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
> >                   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found
> >     incompatible value 'release'.
> >                   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
> >     found incompatible value 'Apk'.
> >                   - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but
> >     wasn't required.
> >                   - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.

**build.gradle of Project A:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.ar.augmented"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':3dviewerobj')
}
```

**build.gradle of Project B:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.andresoviedo.dddmodel2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("android-3d-model-viewer.jks")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias "android-3d-model-viewer"
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Project B is not inside Project A, you only import it in case you want it to do something for you inside Project A Acticity, such intent might not work. Just look for something that will launch another app

Comment: post  your both module 'build.gradle'

Comment: @MilaDroid I updated the answer, check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.projectB.app.another.app.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

and when you creat intent try it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.projectB.app.another.app.ANOTHER_ACTIVITY");
startActivity(intent);
```

I hope it work for you...

Answer (score 0):

change **build.gradle** of *Project B* like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.andresoviedo.dddmodel2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("android-3d-model-viewer.jks")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias "android-3d-model-viewer"
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: i've deleted my answer, hope it helps.